# How to arrange the objects in a certain order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have list of images in a table (create table id, name, sequence). I want to arrange objects in a certain sequence.

e.g.

```
1, "rose", 1
2, "jasmine", 2
3, "lilly", 3
```

If I move "lilly" in front of "rose", the sequence would be as follows

```
1, "rose", 2
2, "jasmine", 3
3, "lilly", 1
```

Is there a way to automatically achieve this via a gem, since I don't want to update all sequence values in the table by writing update code myself.

Comment: set lilly to sequence 0 ? or use sequence with bigger numbers 100,200,300 so can place items between them :)

Comment: I recommend using Floats instead of Integers for sort orders - that way, you can always move any given element between any two others. Need to move something between 1.0 and 2.0? Set it to 1.5. Move another between 1.5 and 2.0? It can be 1.75, and so on. This requires updating only one record, rather than all of them (which doesn't scale particularly well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ActsAsList](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem, which does the position updating work for you when you change the position of a record.